# Why I always getting logs Auth::user() on null in my blade template?

Tags: laravel-5.5

I use `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` on all of my blade templates. It successfully shown the user's name though, but why in my logs it written Auth::user()->name is `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`. These logs just make things go crazy.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code might fail on below code since you don't have a check here if you are logged in or not!

`{{ auth()->user()->name }}`

Comment: It probably true.
`{{ Auth::user() && Auth::user()->name }`
This code is fine. I think we need to handle the exception, even though the app requires user to login first.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes handle exception you need to do. You are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

First clear out the log file empty it. Assuming its `storage/logs/laravel.log`

In terminal use following command to look for the live changes in your log file.

`{project_root} > tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`

if above doesn't work use following:

`{project_root} > sudo tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`

Now, you can keep taps on the log file if anything is logged in it.

Open your browser and terminal/console side by side and go through your App and look for the trigger point when the Exception is logged and shown on the terminal and start debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you login your application. when you login then only you can get info from auth. 
you don't worry about login sign up process in laravel.
just run php artisan make:auth. laravel scaffolding working for you.
this is simple template. you can customize what ever you want.